# File download issue in PHP with Content-Disposition: attachment

Tags: php, zend-framework, download, attachment, content-disposition

I have a link on my web page to download a .CSV file that I have generated on the server. The code for the download is as follows:

```
//open/save dialog box
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="inventoryData.csv"');
//content type
header('Content-type: application/excel');
//read from server and write to buffer
readfile('spreadsheet/inventory.csv');
```

When I open the file on the server, it looks just fine. However, when I download the file via the dialog box, it is pre-pending the HTML code for the web page to the .csv file.

Any ideas why that would happen?

Comment: Are you making sure that there is no other code being echoed out before?

Comment: `application/excel` should be [`text/csv`](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt).

Comment: You might have HTML errors enabled in php.ini.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this code is in a controller action which I assume it is since you are using ZF, then you need to disable your layout and the view renderer as it will try to render a view.

Try:

```
public function downloadAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    //...

    //open/save dialog box
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="inventoryData.csv"');
    //content type
    header('Content-type: application/excel');
    //read from server and write to buffer
    readfile('spreadsheet/inventory.csv');
}
```

`$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();` prevents your layout script from being rendered (assuming you use layouts), and `$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);` tells the view renderer not to render the view script for the controller action which may contain some HTML or whitespace.

Comment: Ah, how did I miss that? Major props to you!

Answer (score -3):

This should do the trick

```
  header("Pragma: public");
  header("Expires: 0");
  header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  header("Cache-Control: private",false);
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"inventoryData.csv\";" );
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

Comment: How is changing the HTTP headers going to stop the HTML data being prepended to the HTTP body?

Answer (score -4):

Try this one:

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition:attachment; filename=inventoryData.csv");
```

Comment: how come im downvoted? im using this code for almost a year now for downloading csv file in my site and it never gives me an error.

Comment: How is using a different, less useful, content-type going to stop HTML data being prepended to the output?

Comment: I'm asking what this has to do with the question.

Comment: so, what do you think is the answer to this question?

Comment: I think the question is unanswerable in its current form and that patyx7's comment addresses how the OP should start debugging it.